# Select query without display

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have this code

```
select A,B,C,
case
when A = B = C then'Equilateral' 
when A + B < C then 'Not A Triangle'
when (A = B and B != C) or (A = C and B != A) or ( B = C and A != B ) then "Isoceles"
else "Scalene"
end,  
from Triangles;
```

I only want it to display the strings `equilateral`, `not a triangle`. Without displaying the column's content. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select what you want.  It would appear to be:

```
select (case when A = B and B = C then 'Equilateral' 
             when A + B < C then 'Not A Triangle'
             when (A = B and B <> C) or (A = C and B <> A) or ( B = C and A <> B ) 
             then 'Isoceles'
             else 'Scalene'
        end)  
from Triangles;
```

Notice that I substituted standard SQL operators in your expressions.  Because of the precedence of `case` and fixing the logic, this can be:

```
select (case when A + B < C or A + C < B or B + C < A then 'Not A Triangle'
             when A = B and B = C then 'Equilateral' 
             when A = B or A = C or B = C 
             then 'Isoceles'
             else 'Scalene'
        end)  
from Triangles;
```

This assumes that `A`, `B`, and `C` are all non-negative.

Comment: Thank you so much !